# Include_once being ignored in Eclipse Neon

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm making a dynamic web project by following along with a tutorial and I'm using Eclipse Neon, Apache Tomcat 8.5, and PHP Development Tools 4.3. I'm trying to split index.php into a header and footer, but include_once 'header.php' doesn't seem to be working, and the only thing that displays when I run index.php is "Home".

Here's index.php

```
<?php 
    include_once 'header.php';
?>

<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
</section>

<?php 
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

And here's header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

            </ul>
            <div class="nav-login">
                <form >
                    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e- 
                    mail">
                    <input type="text" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
                <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

They're both under the WebContent folder, and style.css works when I run header.php on the server. I'm also not getting any type of error as far as I can tell (I'm new to Eclipse and the only thing the console is putting out is info on when the server is stopping and starting).
I've tried looking for solutions to similar questions but haven't gotten anywhere, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using `require_once`  which will raise an error if the file is not found unlike `include_once` which just ignores missing files.  Of course this assumes you have error reporting and display errors turned on. Otherwise you may not see it anyway.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, header.php is still being ignored.

Comment: Are you running it in Eclipse or the browser, I never test stuff in Eclipse itself.  I have 3x 32inch flat screens though ... lol ... I'm spoiled no minimize this and minimize that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running it directly in Eclipse and it opens a new tab to show the web page. Which I also figured out how to get the problems view, and it still doesn't display any kind of error when require_once is used.

Comment: As I said I never test in Eclipse, besides there are differences in all browsers. I always test in all the major ones, Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox and Safari.  The thing eclipse has may be better for command line stuff ... I don't know I never use it, because it's not a good representation of the "real world"  I use Oxygen as it has Composer support (even if it wreaks your build paths, which you have to fix constantly)....  But I started on 3.4 (Ganymede) when PDT was hardly a thing.